# Jenkins execute action after delete build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to execute some action after build has been deleted (by user or automatically) on Jenkins.

Actually, I need the following:

1. Send http-request with info about deleted build.
2. Delete build artifacts on remote location.

About #2: I use Artifact Deployer plugin to deploy build, but because of issue
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26109 build is not deleting on remote location after build has been deleted.

Any way, how I can do something on deleting build? Maybe I have to write script or create plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class [RunListener](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/listeners/RunListener.html) which has method onDeleted.

Do something like this:

```
import hudson.model.Run;
import hudson.model.listeners.RunListener;
import hudson.Extension;

@Extension
public class DeleteListener extends RunListener<Run> {
      @Override
      public void onDeleted(Run r) {
         // your code here
      }
}
```

Moreover, remember that if you delete job - event onDeleted [will not be fired](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26708).

Comment: I tried your code and I always end up with an error: `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: DeleteListener.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), all(), any(), find(), wait(long, int)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Plugin is required for this.
You can write a cron job for this which checks the build directory continuously for any changes in the contents.

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/your_job_here/builds/
```

If any of the folder is deleted that means a build is deleted manually/automatically. Then you can trigger a mail or perform whatever task you want to do as now you know a build has been deleted.